# How to combine two First Name with and followed by Second Name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've huge list of Couple's Name and I want to reorganize the list.

Check the Screen Shot:

[image]

*Below is the Formula I've applied:*

```
=LEFT(E48,FIND(" ",E48&" ")-1) & IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("and",E48))," and " & LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E48,"and",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)),FIND(" ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E48,"and",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))&" ")-1),"")
```

**Note,** *I'm using Office 2013 & 2016.*

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E48,MID(E48,FIND(" ",E48,1+FIND(" ",E48,1+FIND(" ",E48,1+FIND(" ",E48,1)))),65535),"",1)
```

Comment: @RajeshS The formula simply gets whole slack after 4th space char (including it) and removes 1st occurence of this substring from a whole string. If value format is wrong (leading space, double space, etc.) the result will be wrong. So source data must be prepared carefully - remove leading/trailing spaces, replace polyspaces with single spaces.

Comment: @Akina You could also do that within your formula by replacing `E48` with `TRIM(E48)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right, but each additional function in a formula decreases performance...

Comment: I deleted my response after I noted that it uses the same basic algorithm of yours, but you can do that with only two extra `TRIM`'s using a different algorithm for the `Last Word`:  `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"",1)`